# how can we append text to an existing file at remote server through sftp in java?

Tags: java, append, sftp

```
sftpChannel.put(new ByteArrayInputStream(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes()),
                        acquirerFileName,ChannelSftp.APPEND);
```

when I'm trying to append the text to a file through sftp, I'm getting an Exception -> **File already exists**. I can't create the file without the Truncate flag, can someone please help on this?

And in the JSch library, the `ChanneSftp` file contains a  commented code for Append =>

```
    private void sendOPENA(byte[] path) throws Exception{
        sendOPEN(path, SSH_FXF_WRITE|/*SSH_FXF_APPEND|*/SSH_FXF_CREAT);
      }
```

Can someone tell how I can append the text to a file through sftp?

Comment: what version of JSch? What SFTP server is that? Your code works just fine for me against OpenSSH SFTP server.

Comment: <jsch.version>0.1.55</jsch.version>

Comment: i am using simply SFTP  -> sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");


Can you please share your code ?

Comment: There's nothing to share. I've used your code. Does is work for your if you remove the `ChannelSftp.APPEND` (overwrites a file)? + You didn't answer *"What SFTP server is that?"*

Comment: yes it's working for overwrite mode & the sftp server i am using is syncplify.me server.

Comment: Then it's most probably a bug in that server. You should contact their support.

Comment: which SFTP server you are using ?

Comment: I've tested this against OpenSSH (the most common SSH/SFTP server).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it's working fine.
when i am using - 
**OutputStream outputStream = sftpChannel.put(acquirerFileName, ChannelSftp.APPEND);**

Answer (score 0):

The SSH_FXF_APPEND is commented out as the write in

```
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(InputStream, String, SftpProgressMonitor, int)
```

is done with offset:

```
   foo-=sendWRITE(handle, offset, data, _s, foo);
```